# Show that the range of a linear transformation is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb V \to \mathbb W$ be a linear transformation from a vector space $\mathbb V$ into a vector space $\mathbb W$. Prove that the range of $T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb W$.

OK here is my attempt...

If we let $x$ and $y$ be vectors in $\mathbb V$, then the transformation of these vectors will look like this... $T(x)$ and $T(y)$.

If we let $\mathbb V$ be a vector space in $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb W$ be a vector space in $\mathbb R^2$, then

$$
T \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3 
\end{pmatrix} = T\begin{pmatrix} x_1 + 2x_2 \\ 3x_3 + 4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now if we tried to row reduce the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

we would get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} .$

SO the range of $T$ are the linear combinations of the pivot colums of the matrix above.

This is as much as I can do by myself. But now that i think about it, I believe this is wrong because the linear combinations of the pivot columns will give out any vector in $\mathbb R^2$, and not in the subspace of $\mathbb W$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to prove this result for general vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Do you know the characterization of a linear subspace?

Comment: It's better to use descriptive titles. I edited the title to make it more relevant in search results, but @manooooh changed it back to something less useful.....

Answer (score 2):

Given any two vector spaces $\mathbb{V, W}$ over $F$, and $T:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}$ is a linear transformation.

1. $0_\mathbb{V}\in \mathbb{V}$. Since $T$ is linear, $T(0_\mathbb{V})=0_\mathbb{W},$ which implies $0_\mathbb{W}\in R(T).$
2. Given any $x,y\in R(T),$ which implies there exist $v_x,v_y\in \mathbb {V}$ s.t. $T(v_x)=x, T(v_y)=y,$ but this implies for any $c\in F, T(cv_x+v_y)=^\dagger cT(v_x)+T(v_y)=cx+y,$ so $cx+y\in R(T).$

The 1. and 2. complete the proof.

$\dagger:$ linearity of $T:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}$.

Comment: What's $F$? I can't tell from your proof.

Comment: @AlexJohnson: A vector space $\mathbb{V}$ over $F$.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexJohnson: In case of your confusion: Both $\mathbb{V, W}$ should over the same field $F$ (this is how a *linear transformation* should be defined) , that's why the same $c$ on both side of $T(cv_x+v_y)=cx+y$ (the right hand side is a vector of $\mathbb{W}$, while the left hand side of $\mathbb{V}$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a fixed field $k$ and $T : V \to W$ a morphism. What is the range of $T$? We have that $$T(V) = \{T(v) : v \in V\}.$$ Thus we have to show that $T(V) \subseteq W$ is a subspace. Do you know what one has to show for a set being a subspace?

**Comment.** It is a very good idea to get used to a concept by explicitely considering an example like you did and your idea is right.

Answer (score 0):

The range of $T$ is a set inside the vector space $W$. To prove that a subset of a vector space is a subspace, you need to show that the subset is non-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Can you see why the range of $T$ is not empty? Now, pick two arbitrary members of the range of $T$. What can you say about them? How can you prove that their sum (well-defined in $W$) is also in the range of $T$? And similarly for the product with a scalar.

Comment: Since i know that $W$ is a subspace, that means that the addition of any two vectors will always result in another vector in the same subspace, the same logic applies with the product of a scalar and any vector in $W$. The range of T is just another subspace INSIDE $W$, If we choose two vectors in the range of T and add them up, then the result will also be in the range because the range is inside a subspace (and all the rules of a subspace apply)..... Is this correct?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master You do not know (or cannot utilize) that the range is a subspace _before_ you have solved the problem. You pick two vectors in the range. You know these two vectors have a sum in $W$ because you know that $W$ is a vector space. Consider that sum. Prove that it is actually inside the range (for this, you must understand what "range" is). Since your two vectors were arbitrary, then you will have proved that the range is closed under addition. Analogously with scalar multiplication.